# Progressing in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am self-studying precalculus-level mathematics in perhaps a more formal way than usual, which means that I am reading about logic, sets, proofs, etc.

The text I am looking at contains as an example of a statement that is not a proposition the following:

"This sentence is false."

The text provides the following reasoning:

> $\quad$The statement “This sentence is false” is not a proposition because it is neither true nor false. It is an example of a paradox—a situation in which, from premises that look reasonable, one uses apparently acceptable reasoning to derive a conclusion that seems to be contradictory. If the statement “This sentence is false” is true, then by its meaning it must be false. On the other hand, if the given statement is false, then what it claims is false, so it must be true.

I need someone to please elaborate a little more on this explanation. Specifically, I am not quite sure about what it means to "assume" or "suppose" that something is the case. How is this different from asserting the truth of the statement? Second, why is it that if a statement leads to a contradiction, then the statement must not be true? Lastly, this example sometimes doesn't even appear in other texts and it doesn't seem helpful, since it has only confused me. What am I supposed to take from this example and why do some texts omit it?

**For Mauro ALLEGRANZA**:
After reading your answer, I almost felt satisfied with this explanation, which is very similar to your argument.

Let $p$ be the statement that $p$ is false. As you said, from a "reasonable" conception of truth, we know that (0) $p\rightarrow\lnot p$ and (0') $\lnot p\rightarrow p$. We reason as follows:

> (1) $p$ (assumption)
>   (2) $p\rightarrow\lnot p$ from (0)
>   (3) $\lnot p$ from (1) and (2) by modus ponens
>   (4) $p\land\lnot p$ from (1) and (3) by $\land$-introduction

From the assumption that $p$ is true, we derive the contradiction (4) that $p$ is both true and false. Thus, $p$ cannot be true, so it must be false.

But if $p$ is false, we have the following:

> (5) $\lnot p$ (assumption)
>   (6) $\lnot p\rightarrow p$ from (0')
>   (7) $p$ from (5) and (6) by modus ponens
>   (8) $p\land\lnot p$ from (5) and (7) by $\land$-introduction

From the assumption $\lnot p$, we are able to derive the contradiction (8) that $p$ is both true and false. Thus, $\lnot p$ cannot be true.

Since assuming $p$ to be true leads to a contradiction and assuming $p$ to be false leads to a contradiction, $p$ cannot have a truth value, and so it is not a proposition.

However, I became confused when using the following argument.

(1') $p\rightarrow\lnot p$ from (0)
(2') $\lnot p\rightarrow p$ from (0')
(3') $p\leftrightarrow\lnot p$ from (1') and (2') by $\leftrightarrow$-introduction.

Now, since for any statement $p$, $p\leftrightarrow\lnot p$ is a contradiction, i.e, always false, (1') or (2') must be false, as [(1')$\land$(2')]$\rightarrow$(3') is a tautology, with $(3')\equiv F$. However, from our conception of truth, we know that (1') and (2') are both true for this particular statement. Yet, for any *actual* proposition $p$, $(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\land (\lnot p\rightarrow p)$ is a contradiction. What does this mean?

Comment: It is an old "philosophical riddle"; see [Liar Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/).

Comment: The Liar Paradox is linked to [self reference](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/) and this phenomenon is the source of many troubles, but also of some interseting mathematical discoveries: see [Paradoxes and Contemporary Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradoxes-contemporary-logic/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your answer below is exactly what I needed. However, it raised a few more questions. Please see the response above.

Comment: I do not understand why this question has not been more significantly upvoted given that it has been viewed over a hundred times. To me this kind of earnest truthseeking is what the site is supposed to be for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Liar Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liar-paradox/) :

> Consider the sentence **Liar**, which says of itself (i.e., says of **Liar**) that it is false.
>
> > **(Liar)** Liar is false.
>
> This seems to lead to contradiction as follows. If the sentence ‘Liar is false’ is true, then **Liar** is false [because, according to a "reasonable" conception of [truth](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-correspondence/#3), a sentence **S** is true iff **S** corresponds to some fact; **S** is false iff **S** does not correspond to any fact]. But if **Liar** is false, then the sentence ‘Liar is false’ is true [for the same reason].
>
> Since **Liar** just is the sentence ‘Liar is false’, we have it that **Liar** is false if and only if **Liar** is true. But, now, if every sentence is true or false, **Liar** itself is either true or false, in which case — given our reasoning above — it is both true and false. This is a contradiction.
>
> Contradictions, according to many logical theories (e.g., classical logic, intuitionistic logic, and much more) imply absurdity, that is, that every sentence is true.

---

Formally, if we assume (i.e. if we consider as the starting point of our argument) that:

> 1) $p \leftrightarrow \lnot p$

and we consider the law of [Excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle):

> 2) $p \lor \lnot p$

we can formalize the following proof (using [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4)):

3) $p$ --- assumed [a]

4) $p \to \lnot p$ --- from 1) by $\leftrightarrow$-elim

5) $\lnot p$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\to$-elim (*modus ponens*)

> 6) $p \land \lnot p$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\land$-intro

7) $\lnot p$ --- assumed [b]

8) $\lnot p \to p$ --- from 1) by $\leftrightarrow$-elim

9) $p$ --- from 7) and 8) by $\to$-elim (*modus ponens*)

> 10) $p \land \lnot p$ --- from 7) and 9) by $\land$-intro
>
> > 11) $p \land \lnot p$ ---- from 2), 3)-6), 7)-10) by $\lor$-elim, discharging temporary assumptions [a] and [b].

Conclusion, from the assumption: "**Liar** is false if and only if **Liar** is true" we have derived the contradiction "**Liar** is both true and false".

---

A [proposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/#semantics) is a sentence of which we can always determine its truth-value: *true* or *false*. Examples: "the book on my desk is red" or "$2<4$".

Propositional logic is base on a ultra-simplified model of language.. In it, the propositional variables: $p,q,\ldots$ must be replaced by propositions and thus propositions must be "linguistic entities" that can be true or false without expections nor ambiguities, because the semantics of (classical) propositional logic is based on the two truth-values: **T** and **F**.

There are some possible solutions to the paradox: [truth-value gaps](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/#2).

Natural language is quite complex and thus it cannot be described with a simplified model like that of propositional logic: we have to take into account indicative sentences which lacks truth-value.

Comment: What is [a] and [b] referring to in the argument? Also, if we can derive a contradiction $B$ (which in my mind is roughly another statement that "goes against" an assumption, a previously proved theorem, or an axiom) from some statement $A$, then the statement $A$ must be false. Why? My best answer to this is that we have shown that $A\implies B$. In the case that $B$ "goes against" (contradicts?) a previously proved theorem or an axiom, we know that $B$ is false. Hence, $A$ is also false. In the case that $B$ goes against the assumption $A$, how then do we know that $B$  must be false?

Comment: @K.Hotz - [a] and [b] are pointers to the formulae in 3) and 7): they are the temporary assumptions used for $\lor$-elimunation (i.e. poof by cases).

Comment: Yes; $p \leftrightarrow \lnot p$ is a *contradiction* (not only *false*, but **always** false - verify it with a truth-table). The Liar argument is: "if **Liar** is true, then **Liar** is false" and "if **Liar** is false, then **Liar** is true". Thus: "**Liar** is true iff **Liar** is false" - Contradiction !

Comment: Allow me to summarize your answer in order to move on. Within propositional logic, statements have exactly one truth value -- true or false. A statement is true iff it corresponds to some fact, and false iff it does not correspond to any fact. From this conception of truth, we see that the statement (Liar) is true iff it is false. Since every statement has a truth value, (Liar) itself must be either true or false, but in both cases we arrive at a contradiction. Hence, (Liar) is neither true nor false, and is not a proposition. Correct? Ok for a beginner to feel comfortable with and proceed?

Comment: Another thought. Within propositional logic and because of our conception of truth, the nature of (Liar) is that it is true iff it is false. Shouldn't the argument end here? For any proposition $p$, $p\iff\lnot p$ is a contradiction. There is no proposition $p$ for which $p\iff\lnot p$ is true. Hence, (Liar) is not a proposition.

Comment: @K.Hotz - Correct; if we agree that a *proposition* **must** be either *true* or *false* and not both, Liar is not a proposition, that is exactly what your textbook says: "The statement “This sentence is false” is not a proposition because it is neither true nor false. "

Comment: Now (11) confuses me. Why is (11) necessary? The contradiction (6) allows us to discharge the assumption [a], and the contradiction (10) allows us to discharge the assumption [b]. Also, in a comment you wrote, "...they are the temporary assumptions used for $\lor$-elim[i]nation" (i.e. proof by cases)." Aren't $\lor$-elimination and proof by cases different? I can't figure out which is being applied for (11).

Comment: Hmm. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) article is as you say -- that $\lor$-elimination is the same as _proof by cases_. However, [here](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/proofs+concepts.pdf) $\lor$-elimination is $p\lor q$, $\lnot p$, $\therefore q$ and also $p\lor q$,$\lnot q$, $\therefore p$, while proof by cases is $p\rightarrow q$, $r\rightarrow q$, $p\lor r$, $\therefore q$.

Comment: @K.Hotz - the rule: $p∨q , ¬p ∴ q$ is [disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism); it can be derived from $\lor$-elim.

Comment: I have two final questions. First question: What is the reasoning for (11)? My best attempt is that since $[(p\rightarrow\lnot p) \land (\lnot p\rightarrow p) \land (p\lor\lnot p)] \rightarrow (p\land\lnot p)$ is a true implication but the consequent $(p\land\lnot p)$ is false, it follows that the antecedent must be false. However, I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Second question: I understand that from a "reasonable" conception of truth, we have it that $p\leftrightarrow\lnot p$ (for the statement $p$: $p$ is false). But for any proposition $p$, $p\leftrightarrow\lnot p$ is false. Shouldn't the argument end here, since $p$ must not be a proposition?